# EditText input saved in Database

Tags: android, database, android-edittext

I'm really new to Android and i'd like to save the Input of my Edittext into my Database. Here's my Database:

```
    package de.retowaelchli.filterit.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class ADFilterDBAdapter {

        public static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
        public static final String NAME = "name";
        public static final String KEYWORD = "keyword";
        public static final String CACHE = "cache";

        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "adfilter";

        private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

        private final Context mCtx;

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, DBAdapter.DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            }
        }

        /**
         * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
         * opened/created
         * 
         * @param ctx
         *            the Context within which to work
         */
        public ADFilterDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
            this.mCtx = ctx;
        }

        /**
         * Open the cars database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
         * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
         * signal the failure
         * 
         * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
         *         initialization call)
         * @throws SQLException
         *             if the database could be neither opened or created
         */
        public ADFilterDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
            this.mDb = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * close return type: void
         */
        public void close() {
            this.mDbHelper.close();
        }

        /**
         * Create a new car. If the car is successfully created return the new
         * rowId for that car, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
         * 
         * @param name
         * @param model
         * @param year
         * @return rowId or -1 if failed
         */
        public long createADFilter(String name, String keyword, String cache){
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(NAME, name);
            initialValues.put(KEYWORD, keyword);
            initialValues.put(CACHE, cache);
            return this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }

        /**
         * Delete the car with the given rowId
         * 
         * @param rowId
         * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
         */
        public boolean deleteADFilter(long rowId) {

            return this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        /**
         * Return a Cursor over the list of all cars in the database
         * 
         * @return Cursor over all cars
         */
        public Cursor getAllADFilter() {

            return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID,
                    NAME, KEYWORD, CACHE }, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        /**
         * Return a Cursor positioned at the car that matches the given rowId
         * @param rowId
         * @return Cursor positioned to matching car, if found
         * @throws SQLException if car could not be found/retrieved
         */
        public Cursor getADFilter(long rowId) throws SQLException {

            Cursor mCursor =

            this.mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID, NAME,
                    KEYWORD, CACHE}, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }

        /**
         * Update the car.
         * 
         * @param rowId
         * @param name
         * @param keyword
         * @param cache
         * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
         */
        public boolean updateADFilter(long rowId, String name, String keyword,
                String cache){
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(NAME, name);
            args.put(KEYWORD, keyword);
            args.put(CACHE, cache);

            return this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) >0; 
        }

    }
```

Its a Copy of an Other Database i change to work on my own.

Heres my layout.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView 
        style="@style/NormalFont"
        android:text="@string/adconfig"     
        android:layout_weight="0.05" 
        android:clickable="false"
        />

        <TextView
            style="@style/SmallFont"
            android:text="@string/adname"
            android:layout_weight="0.03" />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/ADConfigName" 
            android:layout_weight="0.05" 
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            style="@style/SmallFont"
            android:text="@string/adkeyword"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/ADConfigKeyword" 
            android:layout_weight="0.05" 
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>

            <TextView
            style="@style/SmallFont"
            android:text="@string/adcache"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
             />
        <RadioGroup 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/adcache_true" 
            android:id="@+id/adcache"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <RadioButton 
                android:text="Yes" 
                android:id="@+id/adcache_true" 
                android:layout_width="80dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton 
                android:text="No" 
                android:id="@+id/adcache_falsh" 
                android:layout_width="80dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup> 

        <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ADConfigMainsite"
            android:layout_weight="0.76"
            android:gravity="bottom">   
                <TableRow 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
                    android:id="@+id/ADConfigMainsite"
                    android:onClick="onClickADConfigSave"
                    android:layout_weight="0.05"
                    android:gravity="bottom">
                        <TextView   
                            android:text="@string/adconfigsave" 
                            style="@style/NormalFont"   
                            android:gravity="bottom"/>
                 </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

And heres my Activity:

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ADFilterConfigActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.autodelete_config);


    }
}
```

What do i have to do that it saves my Input text into my Database. 
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 1. In activity's OnCreate() define your editText views from xml file.
    edtTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ADConfigName);
    edtTextKeyword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ADConfigKeyword);


 2. get string from editText views . 
     likes, 
           String name = edtTextName.getText().toString();
           String keyword = edtTextKeyword.getText().toString();


 3. then using these values call your database's insert method. I think its  
     createADFilter( name,keyword,cache)
```

so, simple. :-)

I write this procedure bcoz i want, do coding by yourself with this procedure, then in actually you can know how to connect with database in sqlite. avoid copy paste.
Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ADFilterConfigActivity extends Activity {
ADFilterDBAdapter db_conn;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.autodelete_config);
         try{
                db_conn.openDataBase();
            }
            catch(SQLException sqle)
            {
                System.out.println("error in opening data : "+sqle);
            }

       EditText mEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ADConfigName);
       mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("The key pressed onkeylistenere is having code: "+keyCode);
                    System.out.println("The key pressed onkeylistenere is having event: "+event);
                    showResults();
                    return false;
                }
            });

    }
private static void showResults()
    {
        String texts = mEditText.getText().toString();
        db_conn.createADFilter(text, "any", "any");
    }
}
```